# Position Fixed in SharePoint 

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, css

I'm trying to create an addon product in MOSS 2007 which tries to position an html element in a fixed position inside SharePoint page using JS and CSS. I want to support IE 6+. What are the ways i can do it?

I've the following questions.

1. It is mentioned that position:fixed works in IE7+. But it is not working unless i put a doctype for the html document (by default it runs in a quirk mode). But how can i add doctype to the document dynamically into the page? If i do so will it break any design? Can i have multiple doctypes in a same page?
2. If i try to fix it using css expression (to position the element during scroll, for IE6) i [learnt](http://ajaxian.com/archives/css-expressions-are-no-more-in-ie-8) that IE8 has deprecated CSS expressions.

Its okay if i want to give up IE 6 support.

Any insights on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a doctype by adding it in your page layout to the AdditionalPageHead contentplaceholder - the best way to test if it will break anything is by doing it unfortunately.

This site has a "hack" that seems to work in IE6.  http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/